# Articy:draft 3 unity importer

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I use articy:draft 3 and the unity importer. Based on the Maniac Manfred I try to make a prototype of my game. I have some Dialogue wich got some Dialogue fragment, only the bottom left is empty. When i speak about "Fil XXX" latter, it's one of those 4 Dialogues

[image: http://www.zupimages.net/up/17/11/6xsa.png]
[image: http://www.zupimages.net/up/17/11/wo0e.png]

I set my articyflow player on a dialogue with this code :

```
  public ArticyRef element; //it's a dialogue, one of the Fil xxx
  public ArticyFlowPlayer flow;
  public void OnPointerClick(PointerEventData eventData)
  {
      flow.startOn = element;
      flow.Play();
  }
```

My OnFlowPlayerPaused it's well call, I put :

```
Debug.Log(flowPlayer.AvailableBranches.Count);
flowPlayer.Play();
return;
```

the availaibleBranchesCount it's equal to 0, and the articyflowplayer stay on the Fil xxxx (I tried with the 4 Fil XXX). OnFlowPlayerPaused is not re-call. OnBranchUpdated is call with 0 branch inside the List.
My Flow is set to pause on Dialogue and Dialogue Fragment only, When I set only Dialogue Fragment, I keep the same problem.

I tryed to find what I missed in the Maniac Manfred example, but I don't find at all.

If you have an idea where I have to look up :/

Have a nice day,

Zel'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug in the plugin, if there are no GlobalVariables assign to the Articy Flow Player, it will not use the default one, see:

http://www.nevigo.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=46&t=18136&p=21029#p21029